# How to make source dynamic for vue-i18n

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n

I have this line of code which is outside of `script` tag `<i18n locale="en" src="../../local/en/index/first.json"></i18n>`

This one uses static source, is there a way for me to import a file by setting the `src` dynamically, or better set this as a prop when possible?

Comment: You can't, <i18n> block is static and processed on compilation. I suppose you can add custom messages on useI18n() call or set them globally through setLocalMessage. This depends on your case

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set the file path in data() and pass it dynamically as a prop to i18 component.

you can change this path on demand:

```
  data() {
return {
  locale: 'en',
  dynamicSrc: `../../local/${this.locale}/index/first.json`
};
```

}

and pass it to component:

```
<i18n :src="dynamicSrc"></i18n>
```